# Calling other function in Shiny server

Tags: r, scope, shiny

I am creating an app with the Shiny package in R and I have defined several functions in other scripts. I want to use these functions with the input variables provided by the user so how can I call them in the server script and take account of the reactivity ? does the function have to be defined in the same script ? in that case I should write them inside or outside the shinyServer function?

Thanks!

Comment: you can call those function with `source`

Comment: can you give me a simple example to illustrate please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put all your custom functions in a single file named say "BusinessLogic.R" and then:
1. Use source (as mentioned by Pork Chop in comments above) to refer to this file. 
So in your server.R you would have a line :
source("./BusinessLogic.R")
2. Then call any function in BusinessLogic.R and pass user inputs as parameters.

Comment: Thank you sigmabeta! :) Im going to try this I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @sigmabeta ! it works. how can I mention that your answer is good?